# Pandas: SettingWithCopyWarning even when using .loc[]

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a simple process, trying to add the array `prob_win` as a new column of an existing data frame `df`. They have the same dimension as shown below:

```
print type(prob_win)
print len(prob_win)
print df.shape

<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
799
(799, 1)
```

I then did the following assignment:

```
df['prob_win'] = prob_win
```

The code works but have the following warning:

```
 1 Warning
/opt/conda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:14: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

So I changed to use .loc as the warning said:

```
df.loc[:,'prob_win'] = prob_win
```

But still got the same error. What did I do wrong here? How do I get rid the warning in this case? Thanks!

Comment: bro this question comes over and over and over again. nothing to worry about, just read the documentation to make sure you understand what's going on. Getting tons of these warnings and I am still alive

Comment: what is code above `df['prob_win'] = prob_win` ? some filtering?

Comment: I would guess that the dataframe "df" is already a slice of another dataframe. i.e. you set `df = df_original[someMaskCriteria]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the warning is matter .

```
df=df.assign(prob_win=prob_win)
```

Comment: `assign` is also much faster than `[] =` assignment (even with `loc`). Sometimes I got ridiculously slow time of `[]` assignment, like 1 second for 1000 rows. No problems like that with `assign`.

Comment: @DennisGolomazov yep , sometime it happens . :-)